# Android TextViews not appearing

Tags: android, textview, imageview, scrollview

I need help with this layout file. The problem is that on Android Studio preview this displays as it should, the image has a title at the bottom of the image, and there is text inside the ScrollView under the FAB.
I'm sorry for the lengthy xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_image_view"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:elevation="@dimen/card_height">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_title"
            android:background="@drawable/white_gradient"
            style="@style/large_white_text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/detailed_image_view"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/accent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/location_icon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_location"
            style="@style/normal_text"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/time_date_icon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_date"
            style="@style/normal_text"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/price_icon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_price"
            style="@style/normal_text"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lorem"
                android:id="@+id/detailed_text"
                android:elevation="10dp" />
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_name"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the initialization code

```
ImageView headerImage = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_image_view);
        TextView title = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_title);
        TextView date = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_date);
        TextView location = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_location);
        TextView price = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_price);
        TextView text = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_text);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        EventModel eventModel = bundle.getParcelable("event");

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(eventModel.getImage())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(headerImage);

        title.setText(eventModel.getTitle());
        date.setText(eventModel.getDateString());
        price.setText("Free");
        location.setText(eventModel.getHost());
        text.setText(eventModel.getText());
```

This is how it is supposed to look, but what I get on my phone is no "[PLACEHOLDER]" and lorem ipsum text

[image]

Comment: This is a good question, but you should more clearly state what the specific issue is. What is the specific thing you are trying to achieve and how is it not working? I could give you a short XML to show you how to make a TextView "appear," but I'm guessing you'd like something more specific than that.

Comment: Question is Vague. What are you looking for?

Comment: Try to use a fixed height for your first *RelativeLayout*. Maybe your image height (300dp) + *detailed_title* TextView height fill the full  screen.